# C++ problems returning from a function

Tags: c++, return

I've made a server application for my own personal use, but I've always had a problem when a client disconnects. I've just recently realized that this is caused by the item returned by the `recv` function not being recognized correctly.
For example:

```
char* mrecv(bool show, LPVOID pointerToObject) //Recieve a message
{
    int iResult2 = recv(ClientSocket, recvbuf, 512, 0);
    if (iResult2 > 0) {
        if ((strncmp(recvbuf,"/",1)) != 0) {
            printm(recvbuf, pointerToObject);
       }
    else if (iResult2 == 0) {
        printf("Connection closing...\n");
        closesocket(ClientSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return "1";
    }
    else  {
        printm("recv failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        printm("Client must have disconnected. Please select a new client.");
        return "1";
    }
    return recvbuf;
}
```

When the client disconnects, the function returns "1" correctly to the parent function. However, when I check it as so...:

```
DWORD WINAPI recvfunc(LPVOID pointerToObject)
{
    while (true) {
        ClientSocket=client[currentclient].cs;
        char* p = mrecv(true, pointerToObject);
        std::cout<<p<<"\n";
        if ( p == "1") {
            client[currentclient].con=false;
            ClientSocket=client[lastclient].cs;
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

the `if` statement returns false whether or not the check returns `"1"`, yet `1` prints to the screen flawlessly.

Anyone have any idea why this is happening?

I'm using winsock, if you haven't noticed.

Thanks in advance :)

EDIT::
All of the below answers as of this edit seem to be the same thing, and they all solve the problem. If you look at the first function listed up there ^, you'll see that I apparently even ran across this problem before and had to use this solution. So it looks like my brain just kind of gave up on me. Anyway, thanks for all the assistance. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `mrecv` returns a result of type `char*`.

Your comparison:

```
if (mrecv(true, pointerToObject)=="1")
```

is a pointer comparison, not a string comparison. It's true only if both instances of the string `"1"` happen to be stored at the same address.

To compare strings, use the `strcmp` function. Or, since you're using C++, consider using the `std::string` class (which has an overloaded `==` function that does string comparison) rather than using raw C-style strings.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
if (strcmp(mrecv(true, pointerToObject), "1") == 0)
```

Comment: Oh, my. Thank you very much. I remember having to use that solution earlier in my project, yet it slipped my mind completely.
I'll give it a shot now, but I'm almost certain this is the solution.

Comment: Wait a second... That's even in the first function I listed up there. -.-
Well... Sorry people. My mind just kind of exploded on me I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You're returning pointers to read-only char literals, those addresses are unreliable for a comparison as you're doing.

You might go for a string comparison using [strcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) or any other C++ string comparison

```
if ( strcmp(p,"1") == 0) { ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing char pointers, and there is no guarantee one pointer will be equal to the other:

Try this:

```
if (mrecv(true, pointerToObject)[0] == '1')
```

You are now comparing the first byte returned by `mrecv` to the character `1`.

However, I highly recommend you return integer return codes, not characters.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you can't use the == operator in that fashion with C-style strings (char arrays) because what's being compared is not the contents of the string, but the value of the pointer to the first character, since you're really comparing a char* to a char*.  If you want to compare the actual value, you need to dereference the returned pointer and also compare it to a character value instead of a string literal (single quotes instead of double):

```
if (*mrecv(true, pointerToObject) == '1') {
```

Comment: Doing `mrecv(true, pointerToObject)[0]` would probably be more readable and make it more obvious that you're dealing with a C-String